# Merchant's Guide to the Galaxy

Tags: java, programming-challenge

This is my version of [Merchant's Guide to the Galaxy](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=4904931328786432):

> A merchant buys and sells items in the galaxy. Buying and selling over
>   the galaxy requires you to convert numbers and units. The numbers used
>   for intergalactic transactions follows similar convention to the roman
>   numerals. Roman numerals are based on seven symbols:
>
> - I 1
> - V 5
> - X 10
> - L 50
> - C 100
> - D 500
> - M 1000
>
> Numbers are formed by combining symbols together and adding the
>   values. For example, MMVI is 1000 + 1000 + 5 + 1 = 2006. Generally,
>   symbols are placed in order of value, starting with the largest
>   values. When smaller values precede larger values, the smaller values
>   are subtracted from the larger values, and the result is added to the
>   total. For example MCMXLIV = 1000 + (1000 − 100) + (50 − 10) + (5 − 1)
>   = 1944.
>
> The symbols "I", "X", "C", and "M" can be repeated three times in
>   succession, but no more. (They may appear four times if the third and
>   fourth are separated by a smaller value, such as XXXIX.) "D", "L", and
>   "V" can never be repeated. "I" can be subtracted from "V" and "X"
>   only. "X" can be subtracted from "L" and "C" only. "C" can be
>   subtracted from "D" and "M" only. "V", "L", and "D" can never be
>   subtracted. Only one small-value symbol may be subtracted from any
>   large-value symbol. A number written in [16]Arabic numerals can be
>   broken into digits. For example, 1903 is composed of 1, 9, 0, and 3.
>   To write the Roman numeral, each of the non-zero digits should be
>   treated separately. Inthe above example, 1,000 = M, 900 = CM, and 3 =
>   III. Therefore, 1903 = MCMIII. Input to your program consists of lines
>   of text detailing your notes on the conversion between intergalactic
>   units and roman numerals. You are expected to handle invalid queries
>   appropriately.
>
> Test input:
>
> - glob is I
> - prok is V
> - pish is X
> - tegj is L
> - glob glob Silver is 34 Credits
> - glob prok Gold is 57800 Credits
> - pish pish Iron is 3910 Credits
> - how much is pish tegj glob glob?
> - how many Credits is glob prok Silver?
> - how many Credits is glob prok Gold?
> - how many Credits is glob prok Iron?
> - how much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?
>
> Test output:
>
> - pish tegj glob glob is 42
> - glob prok Silver is 68 Credits
> - glob prok Gold is 57800 Credits
> - glob prok Iron is 782 Credits
> - I have no idea what you are talking about

I would appreciate suggestions on how to better break up my code into different classes, more efficient ways to have done it or a better way to have done it without using many `if` statements, or more ways to have used Java 8.

```
public class ParseInput {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        String filePath = "/Users/s/interviews/tw/testinput.txt";

        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))){
            lines
                    .forEach(line -> RomanNumerals.parse(line));
        }
        catch (IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}


    public class RomanNumerals {

    static Map<String, String> howMuchMoney = new HashMap<>();


    public static int romanToInt(String s) {
        int nums[] = new int[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            switch (s.charAt(i)) {
                case 'M':
                    nums[i] = 1000;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    nums[i] = 500;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    nums[i] = 100;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    nums[i] = 50;
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    nums[i] = 10;
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    nums[i] = 5;
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    nums[i] = 1;
                    break;

            }

        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            if (nums[i] < nums[i + 1])
                sum -= nums[i];

            else {
                sum += nums[i];
            }


        } return sum + nums[nums.length - 1];
    }




    public static void whichMetal(String s, String metal) {


        double sum = 0;

        String[] output = s.split(Pattern.quote(metal));

        // Galatic words before the type of metal

        String individualWords = output[0];
        String[] outputWords = individualWords.split(" ");

        String romanNumeral = "";

        // Convert galactic words to Roman numerals

        for (String ow : outputWords) {
            romanNumeral += howMuchMoney.get(ow);
        }

        // Convert Roman numerals to regular numbers

        double convertedInt = romanToInt(romanNumeral);

        String creditWords = output[1];

        // Splits the part of the String before Credit so that we get the number

        String[] creditOutputWords = creditWords.split(" ");

        int money = creditOutputWords.length - 2;

        double creditMoney = Double.parseDouble(creditOutputWords[money]);

        // Divides the number of credits by the value before the metal so we get the value for one unit of that metal
        double valueToInsert = 0;
        if (convertedInt !=0 ) {
            valueToInsert = creditMoney / convertedInt;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("creditMoney " + creditMoney);
            System.out.println("convertedInt " + convertedInt);
        }
        // inserts the value of metal and the numeric value into the hashmap

        howMuchMoney.put(metal, Double.toString(valueToInsert));
    }

    static void translate(String s, String separator){

        double sum = 0;

         DecimalFormat df2  = new DecimalFormat("");

        // Splits the string based on whether we are asking how much or how many Credits

        String[] output = s.split(Pattern.quote(separator));

        // Intergalatic words (plus metal), ie glob prok Silver or tegj glob glob

        String individualWords = output[1];

        String[] outputWords = individualWords.split(" ");

        String romanNumeral ="";

        double value =0;

        for (String ow: outputWords){

            if (!ow.equals("")) {


                if (!ow.equals("Silver") && (!ow.equals("Gold") && (!ow.equals("Iron")))) {

                    // Gets Roman numeral for the Galatic words ( sentence doesn't have Credits)

                    romanNumeral += howMuchMoney.get(ow);

                }
                else {


                    // Gets Roman numeral before the metal

                    value= Double.parseDouble(howMuchMoney.get(ow));
                  //  System.out.println("with metals " + romanNumeral);

                    // Multiplies the number of units of the metal by the value of the metal

                    sum = value * romanToInt(romanNumeral);

                    // Remove the last space and ? and also show without decimals

                    System.out.println(output[1].trim().replaceAll(" \\?", "") +" is " + df2.format(sum).toString().replaceAll(",", "") + " Credits");
                }
            }

        }

        // Only prints out if it is not How many credits (since that has already been printed out)

         if (!output[1].contains("Silver") && !output[1].contains("Gold") && !output[1].contains("Iron"))
        System.out.println(output[1].trim().replaceAll(" \\?", "") + " is " + romanToInt(romanNumeral));

    }

    public static boolean validate(String s){
        if (s.contains("DD") || s.contains("LL") || s.contains("VV") || s.contains("MMMM") || s.contains("CCCC") || s.contains("XXXX"))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }


    public static void parse(String s){



        boolean validString = validate(s);

        if (validString == true) {

            if (s.contains("how many Credits")) {
                translate(s, "how many Credits is");
            } else if (s.contains("Silver")) {

                whichMetal(s, "Silver");

            } else if (s.contains("Gold")) {
                whichMetal(s, "Gold");
            } else if (s.contains("Iron")) {
                whichMetal(s, "Iron");
            } else if (s.contains("how much is")) {
                translate(s, "how much is ");
            } else if (!s.equals("") && s.contains("is")) {
                String delimiter = " is ";

                String[] output = s.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter));

                howMuchMoney.put(output[0], output[1]);
            } else System.out.println("I have no idea what you are talking about");

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("The string is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashMap` for storing the integer values aligned with the corresponding letters instead of using switch case.

i.e.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
hmap.put("M", 1000);
hmap.put("D", 500);
hmap.put("C", 100);
hmap.put("L", 50);
hmap.put("X", 10);
hmap.put("V", 5);
hmap.put("I", 1);
```

And retrieve them in the following manner:

```
String var = hmap.get("M"); //where you get 1000 in var.
```

You can iterate through the `HashMap` using an `Iterator` like this:

```
Set set = hmap.entrySet();
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
}
```